# require "soap/wsdlDriver" can't load with soap4r gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, soap4r

I am using ruby version 2.0.0, and Using soap4r (1.5.8).
 But i couldn't able to load require "soap/wsdlDriver".

I am trying to use with in rails console,

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'soap/rpc/driver'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'soap/rpc/driver'
=> false
irb(main):003:0> require "soap/wsdlDriver"
=> false
```

Comment: `require` returns false when the library has been loaded. Check if you can use the utility in soap4r directly.

Answer (score 2):

The standard soap library was removed from Ruby. You will need to find an other solution. Perhaps this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/soap4r-ruby1.9

Or you refactor you code to use a more up-to-date client. Find a list here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/soap